# Flutter CI/CD No space left on device

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I was trying to integrate Gitlab's CI/CD pipeline into my flutter project, I came across this error concerning the available space in the VMs used to perform the various jobs.
Is there any way I can solve this problem?

```
  LLVM ERROR: IO failure on output stream: No space left on device
  clang++: error: unable to execute command: Aborted (core dumped)
  clang++: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      /opt/android-sdk-linux/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \
        -C \
        /home/mobiledevops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.8/android/.cxx/Debug/4158v276/x86 \
        rive_text
    from /home/mobiledevops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.8/android
```

this is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: mobiledevops/flutter-sdk-image

stages:
  - build


# Build APK
build_release_android:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - flutter upgrade
    - flutter doctor
  script:
    - flutter pub get
    - flutter pub global activate flutter_launcher_icons
    - export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
    - flutter build apk --release
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
    expire_in: 1 week


# Build APK
build_debug_android:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - flutter upgrade
    - flutter doctor
  script:
    - flutter pub get
    - flutter pub global activate flutter_launcher_icons
    - export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
    - flutter build apk --debug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
    expire_in: 1 week
```